# Reference YAML keyword file for DRY controller code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I want to be able to use globally accessible symbols throughout my rails app in order to print or return a set of easily maintainable strings/sentences. I've heard of a way using YAML before but I can't remember the specifics of it's implementation or what it's called.

An example how I ideally imagine it would work:

#### Controller

```
def foo
  if token.expired?
    render json: { message: :token_expiry_message }
  end
end

def bar
  if !user.authenticate
    flash[:notice] = :token_expiry_message
  end
end
```

#### Yaml file somewhere

```
token_expiry_message: "The user token is expired, please re-authenticate"
```

This way I can DRY up my controller code and use a standard language set throughout my app by referring them from the YAML file.

Comment: just use locales files located in config/locales. you can set the default locale in application.rb - config.i18n.default_locale = :en which will map to en.yml in config/locales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using built in internationalization stuff

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

in `config/locals/locale.yml` (Where locale is your current local such as en)..

```
 en:
     token_expiry_message: "Your token has expired, please get another"
```

then you can use just the `t()` helper.   such has

```
  def foo
      if token.expired?
        render json: { message: t(:token_expiry_message) }
      end
    end

    def bar
      if !user.authenticate
        flash[:notice] = "Error: " + t(:token_expiry_message)
      end
    end
```

has the added benefit of being able to provide localized versions of the error messages.

Comment: I like this implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a Settings.yml file for this. You can also get deeper into it and use localization files if you need to support multiple languages.

In your Settings.yml:

```
token_expiry_message: 'The user token is expired, please re-authenticate'
```

This can then be loaded into your code via:

```
def foo
  if token.expired?
    render json: { message: Settings.token_expiry_message }
  end
end

def bar
  if !user.authenticate
    flash[:notice] = "Error: #{Settings.token_expiry_message}"
  end
end
```